# Limitations of LSTMs

Tags: long-short-term-memory, sequence-modeling

I'm training an LSTM model for classification on accelerometer data, and I get better results when I downsample the signal to 25 Hz than when I use a 50 Hz signal.

I use the same time frame of 1.5 seconds. So with a 25 Hz signal, I have 37 data points; with a 50 Hz signal, I have 75 data points as input to my model.

I think that LSTM models have a harder time dealing with long sequences, which might explain this difference. However, I am not sure about that claim. Are you aware of any publications that go into depth about the limitations of LSTMs for long sequence tasks?

Answer (score 0):

It is a general problem in neural network, when you go deeper, you may have gradient explosion/vanishing problems. You may try to use gradient-clipping for you particular network.

Comment: Do you have any specific references that highlight this problem?

Comment: Check it please: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhXZsFVxGKo

Comment: But are you aware of an academic paper on the topic?

Comment: Isn't LSTM specifically designed to avoid exploding/vanishing gradients?